# How to update user profile in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to update user profile and i read [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users). But, why i can't change my `displayName` ?it always give me `null`.

And it also give me `TypeError: userNow is null`.

Which one i should follow to update / edit user profile ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Update User Profile</title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="core.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var authRef = firebase.auth();
            authRef.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    console.log('Display name onAuthStateChanged : '+user.displayName);
                } else {
                    console.log('not login');
                }
            });
            
            
            var userNow = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            userNow.updateProfile({
                displayName: "Jane Q. User",
                photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
            }).then(function() {
                var displayName = userNow.displayName;
                var photoURL = userNow.photoURL;
            }, function(error) {
                
            });

        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure your user is actually logged in before you try to update his profile. Remember firebase works asynchronous (including login) so it can take some time before an action is actually finished.

Comment: hai @AndréKool , i already login from another page, and from `onAuthStateChanged` i can get all information from user, including email, uid, etc.

Comment: where are you performing the login, could you post that code? Also, did you check if the name changes looking directly on firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/)?

Comment: if `userNow is null.` than you did not log in successfully.  Before to update the user detail, need to be sure logged in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap your code starting `var userNow = firebase.auth().currentUser;` in a functions.  And as @Andre Kool said, you need to be sure first you sidned in (as it is async operation then try to update user data as:

```
    var authRef = firebase.auth();
    authRef.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log('Display name onAuthStateChanged : '+user.displayName);
            _updateUserData();
        } else {
            console.log('not login');
        }
    });
          
    function _updateUserData(){
      var userNow = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        userNow.updateProfile({
        displayName: "Jane Q. User",
        photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
      }).then(function() {
        var displayName = userNow.displayName;
        var photoURL = userNow.photoURL;
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use **useState** To grap The Value

```
 <input
      className="h-[30px] rounded-2xl p-5"
      placeholder="new name"
      onChange={(e) => setUpdateName(e.target.value)}
      type="text"
  />

 const [updateprofileUrl, setUpdateProfileUrl] = useState();
  const [updatename, setUpdateName] = useState();
  const updateProfileitems = async () => {
    try {
        await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
        displayName: updatename,
        photoURL: updateprofileUrl,
      });
       console.log("Profile Update");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The more modern way to [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) the user profile is using the Firebase Web modular API. You need to be logged in first of course.

```
import { getAuth, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
});
```